# True OR False. Provide a proof or a counterexample

Tags: discrete-mathematics

True OR False. Prove a proof or a counter-example:

**If A∩B = Ø then  ℘(A)∩℘(B) = Ø**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$={$c:c=2M$ for any natural $M$} and $B$={$y:y=2M+1$ for any natural $M$}. Okay so $A\cap B$ is the empty set. Take $f:x\mapsto 2x$. Now $f(x)\cap f(y)$ is not the empty set. I'm assuming you don't include ${0}\in{Naturals}$.

Answer (score 4):

For *any* set $A$ you have $\varnothing \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, so $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B) \ne \varnothing$ whether $A \cap B = \varnothing$ or not.